# Spring Dependency Injection: How to Instantiate Class based on system property?

Tags: java, spring

consider this example

I have interface

```
interface FSClient
  String getMeData()
```

and classes implementing it

```
class MockFSClient implements FSClient {
  public String getMeData() {
    return “I am mock”;
  }
}



class RestFSClient implements FSClient {
  public String getMeData() {
    final String data = // from web service
    return data;
  }
}
```

and a manager which looks like

```
class FSManager {
  private FSClient fsclient;
  @Autowired
  public void FSManager(@Nonnull final FSClient fsClient) {
     this.fsclient = fsClient;
  }
}
```

I want to instantiate `fsclient` based on a system property

```
com.fs.mock=true
```

meaning if `com.fs.mock=true`, `fsclient` should be `MockFSClient` else `fsClient` should be `RestFSClient`

How can I do that?

**Why do I need it?**
so that I can decouple and do testing

Please help, I am new to Spring

Comment: I would make a factory that creates different interfaces depending on com.fs.mock=true and then return the right one.

Comment: You're just asking how to retrieve the system property, correct?  I can't speak towards using full annotation configuration, but when using XML configuration, you can retrieve the values of system properties by using `${property}` notation.

Answer (score 3):

Use profiles

```
...
    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="b1" class="MockFSClient" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="uat,prod">
        <bean id="b1" class="RestFSClient" />
    </beans>
...
```

... -Dspring.profiles.active=dev ...

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how you get the value of `com.fs.mock` because the answer is use the `@Value` annotation and a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/) bean.

If you are asking how do you create the actual object then as @Jakkra says use a factory that contains an if statement around the value of `com.fs.mock`. Its not the most elegant solution but it would work.

Example

```
public class ClientFactory {
    @Value("${com.fs.mock}")
    private boolean mockFlag;

    public static returnClientInstance(){
        if(mockFlag){
            return new MockFSClient();
        }
        else{
            return new RestFSClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to use profiles as described by *Evgeniy Dorofeev* in which case you wouldn't need your custom System property. But here's another solution if you were to stick to your custom System property using **Conditional Bean Configuration**.

In this approach you would need two custom Conditions to encapsulate your conditions:

```
public class MockFSCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String fsMockProperty = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("com.fs.mock");
        return fsMockProperty!=null && fsMockProperty.toLowerCase().equals("true");
    }
}

public class RestFSCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String fsMockProperty = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("com.fs.mock");
        return fsMockProperty==null || !fsMockProperty.toLowerCase().equals("true");
    }
}
```

In which case your configuration class would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"your.beans.package"})
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public FSClient mockFSClient(){
        return new MockFSClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public FSClient restFSClient(){
        return new RestFSClient();
    }

    @Bean(name="fsManager")
    @Conditional(MockFSCondition.class)
    public FSManager mockFsManager() {
        return new FSManager(mockFSClient());
    }


    @Bean(name="fsManager")
    @Conditional(RestFSCondition.class)
    public FSManager restFsManager() {
        return new FSManager(restFSClient());
    }
}
```

Notice that we have created two beans with the same name `fsManager` each one of which is annotated with the two conditions above.

So now at runtime Spring would look for that custom System prop and given whether it's there/correct or not it will instantiate the correct version of `FSManager` constructor-injected with the right `FSClient`.

Comment: but in the case of `@Profile` also, I would have to set the `spring.active.profiles`, isn't it?

Comment: yes indeed you would but this is not a custom system prop (by custom i mean not bound to your specific application but rather Spring actively looking for it).